# Trouble using multiple IF statements in Excel

Tags: excel

The formula I'm currently using is

```
=IF($X$4="in",IF(OR(T6="PLATE", T6="EXTR", T6="FLAT"),W7*25.4+10,IF(T6="SHEET",W7*25.4+50,IF(T6="ROUND",ROUNDUP(W7*25.4+8,)))), IF(OR(T6="PLATE", T6="EXTR", T6="FLAT"),W7+10,IF(T6="SHEET",W7+50,IF(T6="ROUND",ROUNDUP(W7+8,)))))
```

However, now I need to include an additional condition at the beginning that seems to be a step too far for the formula to calculate `- IF(K6="SF", W6*25.4+100)`. If `K6` does not `=SF` then I need it to carry on with the formula as usual.

I've tried juggling it around multiple different ways, but I just can't get it to work. Is it possible?

Comment: Your formula is so complicated, it becomes unreadable. Although, if you program it in VBA, the readability might hugely increase. Therefore I'd advise you to create this function in VBA, and to add the extra loop in there too.

Comment: @Dominique you don't need to change the language to improve the readability :)

Comment: @Olly: having seen (and rewarded) your answer, I can't agree more :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This becomes easier to deal with if you format (and indent) your formula like code.

Here's your existing formula:

```
=IF(
    $X$4="in",
    IF(
        OR(
            T6="PLATE", 
            T6="EXTR", 
            T6="FLAT"
        ),
        W7*25.4+10,
        IF(
            T6="SHEET",
            W7*25.4+50,
            IF(
                T6="ROUND",
                ROUNDUP(W7*25.4+8,)
            )
        )
    ),
    IF(
        OR(
            T6="PLATE", 
            T6="EXTR", 
            T6="FLAT"
        ),
        W7+10,
        IF(
            T6="SHEET",
            W7+50,
            IF(
                T6="ROUND",
                ROUNDUP(W7+8,)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now we can add the additional `IF` statement:

```
=IF(
    K6="SF", 
    W6*25.4+100,
    IF(
        $X$4="in",
        IF(
            OR(
                T6="PLATE", 
                T6="EXTR", 
                T6="FLAT"
            ),
            W7*25.4+10,
            IF(
                T6="SHEET",
                W7*25.4+50,
                IF(
                    T6="ROUND",
                    ROUNDUP(W7*25.4+8,)
                )
            )
        ),
        IF(
            OR(
                T6="PLATE", 
                T6="EXTR", 
                T6="FLAT"
            ),
            W7+10,
            IF(
                T6="SHEET",
                W7+50,
                IF(
                    T6="ROUND",
                    ROUNDUP(W7+8,)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that new condition, you could use:

```
=IF(K6="SF", W6*25.4+100,IF($X$4="in",IF(OR(T6={"PLATE","EXTR","FLAT"}),W7*25.4+10,IF(T6="SHEET",W7*25.4+50,IF(T6="ROUND",ROUNDUP(W7*25.4+8,)))), IF(OR(T6={"PLATE","EXTR","FLAT"}),W7+10,IF(T6="SHEET",W7+50,IF(T6="ROUND",ROUNDUP(W7+8,))))))
```

I haven't addressed the fact that you haven't provided an *else* option for all your IF functions.